# Node.js - Getting empty files when unzipping and uploading to GCS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, unzip

I am trying to create a service that gets a zip file, unpacks it, and uploads its contents to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
The unzipping part seems to work well, but in my GCS bucket all the files seem to be empty.
I'm using the following code:

```
app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

    const uuid = uuidv4();

    console.log(files.filetoupload.path); // temporary path to zip

    fs.createReadStream(files.filetoupload.path)
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on('entry', function (entry) {
            var fileName = entry.path;
            var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
            var size = entry.size;

            const gcsname = uuid + '/' + fileName;
            const blob = bucket.file(gcsname);

            const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream(entry.path);
            blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

            blobStream.on('finish', () => {
                const publicUrl = format(`https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`);
                console.log(publicUrl); // file on GCS
            });

            blobStream.end(entry.buffer);

        });

    });
});
```

I'm quite new to Node.js so I'm probably overlooking something - I've spent some time on documentation but I don't quite know what to do.
Could someone advise on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The fs.createWriteStream() takes file path as argument but GCS createWriteStream() takes [options](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#createWriteStream)

As per the example in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) the recommended way would be:

```
const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });
```

instead of:

`const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream(entry.path)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your buffer is undefined or not . It may be due to unspecified disk/Mem storage that the buffer remains undefined .